# usb-creator-kde fail to install bootable kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb, installation, kubuntu

I want to install a bootable kubuntu 12.04.3 LTS on my Kingston flash drive (1,9GB storage). I've already tried it twice so far and the flash drive didn't start from USB, although I made sure that BIOS has USB as the first setting (it's USB, DVD, HDD respectively).

I use usb-creator-kde. I read it is advised to format the flash drive entirely, so I click *clear disk content* (on the flash drive), then I get a dozen of options to install the system on:

[image]

What does it mean, what the heck is that? Just to make it clear - yes, I've got a single USB drive.

Pojemność = capacity, Wolne miejsce = free space.

Answer (score 1):

So I potentially recently had the same problem trying to make a bootable usb with Linux Mint off of a Linux Mint distribution on my desktop. The problem was that whatever usb creator comes stock with Mint wasn't installing a bootloader that was compatible with UEFI. If instead of BIOS you have a UEFI system this may be your problem. I solved it by installing the gnome version of start-up disk creator `usb-creator-gtk`.

Answer (score 0):

Try unmounting the partition and creating a new FAT32 filesystem on it, to be sure it's completely clean and empty. You can do it from graphical interface ([see there for the howto](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive)) or from shell :

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
sudo mkdosfs -F 32 /dev/sdb1
```

You may also try an other bootable usb creator. I personally use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), and it never failed me.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Arch Linux USB Installation Media](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Flash_Installation_Media#Using_UNetbootin) manpage:

> UNetbootin can be used on any Linux distribution or Windows to copy your iso to a USB device. However, Unetbootin overwrites syslinux.cfg, so it creates a USB device that does not boot properly. For this reason, Unetbootin is **not recommended**

Unfortunately this comment applies to other Linux distros, including Kubuntu (trust me, I am writing from Kubuntu 13.10). Instead, the recommended way to create a USB installation medium is to issue, as root, the following command:

```
 dd bs=4M if=/path/to/kubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX && sync
```

sdX is your USB device. Three important caveats:

1) You will have to find out which one it is all by yourself, and you **must** be careful, because the above command, just like unetbootin or any such utility, will wipe everything off sdX.

2) it is `/dev/sdb` (if the drive letter is `b`), **not** /dev/sdb1.

3) The flash drive must be inserted but unmounted. If you have a system that automatically mounts USB pens, please use `sudo umount ...` to unmount the drive before dd'ing it.

The last command, `sync`, just flashes the file system buffers.